# Renderscript hangs device

Tags: renderscript

I am implementing part of FFT algorithm using Renderscript in Android, When I ran the code my application got hanged. I want to process 512 values from real and img allocation at a time. Kernel will execute 512 times using provided dummy allocation of size 512.

Here is my java code

```
RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(WajinViewerApplication
            .getApplication());
    ScriptC_fft scriptC_fft = new ScriptC_fft(rs);

    float inReal[] = new float[512 * 512];
    float inImg[] = new float[512 * 512];
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 512; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 512; j++) {
            // copy values from complex 2d array to 1d array
            inReal[k] = data[i][j].real;
            inImg[k] = data[i][j].imaginary;
            k++;
        }
    }

    Allocation realAllocation = Allocation.createSized(rs, Element.F32(rs),
            512 * 512);
    Allocation imgAllocation = Allocation.createSized(rs, Element.F32(rs),
            512 * 512);
    realAllocation.copyFrom(inReal);
    imgAllocation.copyFrom(inImg);


    scriptC_fft.set_real(realAllocation);
    scriptC_fft.set_img(imgAllocation);

    Allocation inAllocation = Allocation.createSized(rs, Element.U16(rs),
            512);
    Allocation outAllocation = Allocation.createTyped(rs,
            inAllocation.getType());
    inAllocation.copyFrom(new short[512]);

    // set direction
    if (direction == Direction.Forward) {
        scriptC_fft.set_is_forward(true);
    } else {
        scriptC_fft.set_is_forward(false);
    }

    scriptC_fft.set_len(512);
    scriptC_fft.set_levels(Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(512));

    scriptC_fft.forEach_root(inAllocation, outAllocation);
    outAllocation.copyTo(new short[512]);

    float outReal[] = new float[512 * 512];
    float outImg[] = new float[512 * 512];

    scriptC_fft.get_real().copyTo(outReal);
    scriptC_fft.get_img().copyTo(outImg);

    k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 512; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 512; j++) {
            // copy values from complex 1d array to 2d array
            data[i][j].real = outReal[k];
            data[i][j].imaginary = outImg[k];
            k++;
        }
    }

    rs.destroy();
```

And here is my Renderscript code

```
#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(jp.drmh.wajin.newversion)
#include "common.rsh"

rs_allocation real;
rs_allocation img;
bool is_forward;
uint32_t len;
uint32_t levels;

uint16_t __attribute__((kernel)) root(uint16_t in, uint32_t x, uint32_t y){
//  rsDebug("call",x);

    float realval[512];
    float imagval[512];


    if(is_forward){
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            realval[i]=rsGetElementAt_float(real,x*512+i);
            imagval[i]=rsGetElementAt_float(img,x*512+i);
            //rsDebug("values", realval[i], imagval[i]);
        }
    }else{
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            realval[i]=rsGetElementAt_float(img,x*512+i);
            imagval[i]=rsGetElementAt_float(real,x*512+i);
        }
    }

    float costable[256],sintable[256];

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < len / 2; i++) {
         costable[i]=cos(2 * M_PI * i / len);
         sintable[i]=sin(2 * M_PI * i / len);
    }

    // Bit-reversed addressing permutation
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        uint32_t j = bit_reverse32(i);
        uint32_t ans=j>>(32 - levels);
        if (j > i) {
            float temp = realval[i];
            realval[i] = realval[j];
            realval[j] = temp;
            temp = imagval[i];
            imagval[i] = imagval[j];
            imagval[j] = temp;
        }
    }


    for (uint32_t size = 2; size <= len; size *= 2) {
        uint32_t halfsize = size / 2;
        uint32_t tablestep = len / size;
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < len; i += size) {
            for (uint32_t j = i, k = 0; j < i + halfsize; j++, k += tablestep) {
            float tpre=realval[j + halfsize] * costable[k]
                        + imagval[j + halfsize] * sintable[k];
                float tpim = -realval[j + halfsize] * sintable[k]
                        + imagval[j + halfsize] * costable[k];
                realval[j + halfsize] = realval[j] - tpre;
                imagval[j + halfsize] = imagval[j] - tpim;
                realval[j] += tpre;
                imagval[j] += tpim;
            }
        }
    if (size == len)
            break;
    }


    if(!is_forward){
        for(uint32_t i = 0; i < len; i++){
            realval[i]=realval[i]/len;
            imagval[i]=imagval[i]/len;
            rsDebug("values", realval[i], imagval[i]);
        }

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {

        rsSetElementAt_float(real, realval[i], x*512+i);
        rsSetElementAt_float(img, imagval[i], x*512+i);
        }
    }



    return in;
}
```